# Regex Search and Replace Pattern Needed

Tags: regex

I converted a pdf to an epub file using calibre. When I view the epub, I can see unnecessary line breaks when I view it on my smartphone.

I'd like to use regex to identify these situtations:

```
<lower_case_character><space_character></p><p class="calibre2"><lower_case_character>
```

and convert it to:

```
<lower_case_character><space_character><lower_case_character>
```

Can someone provide me the proper search and replace regex expressions?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do? Remove `</p><p class="calibre2">`? A simple replaceall doesnt work? What technology (language/program) are you using?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove </><p class="calibre2">. I tried [a-z]\b</p><p class="calibre2">[a-z] using this website just as a quick check: http://www.myregextester.com/index.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to remove the unnecessary class attributes added by Calibre.. 
I dont know are trying to make a script that converts pdf to epub OR you want to edit ePub separately. 
To edit the ePub and remove the useless classes you can easily Extract the ePub File.
You can use WinRar, to extract the contents of epub to a folder, Edit the HTML files generated. And then re-Zip it again to make it an ePub.

Comment: Yes, I'm able to open the epub file and get at the HTML file. I could access the regex in C# to find and replace the markup, if I knew the proper search/replace regex patterns, but I don't. That's why I'm asking. :) This is a one time case, so I might just copy the HTML and do a search and replace in OpenOffice using regex. Yes, I want to remove the </p><p class="calibre2"> tags but only if it's a break in the middle of a sentence.

Comment: You should use a HTML Editor eg. NVU Editor and since the changes are to be made based on Logic, it would be better to recognize the wrongly formatted style applied.

Also the ePub result also varies from one Reader App to another

Comment: That's very labor intensive to use logic and an editor. I dont want to manually do a search and replace on all the </p><p class="calibre2"> instances. I only want to do the replace when that markup is in mid-sentence. Thus, I can let regex do the heavy lifting to identify when the markup is splitting a sentence. That markup exists between the end of the sentence and the beginning of the next sentence also which I don't want to replace. I only want to replace the ones in mid-sentence.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the editor you are using has lookaround capabilities, try this for the "search":

```
(?<=[a-z])\b</p><p class="calibre\d">(?=[a-z])
```

In the "replace" simply put a space.

In the code above, this `(?<=[a-z])` is a "positive lookbehind" that looks for, but does not replace a lower case letter preceding the block of text you want to replace.

Likewise, this `(?=[a-z])` is a "positive lookahead" that looks for, but does not replace a lower case letter after the block of text you want to replace.

The \d after "calibre" `calibre\d` should catch other classes, such as calibre1 or calibre3, etc.

You can try it out here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

The following is a little more robust and will look for the Calibre tags that may have extra whitespace on either side of the tags:

```
(?<=[a-z])(\b|\s)(</p><p class="calibre\d">)(\b|\s)(?=[a-z])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?x) (?<! \. (co|d ) )
(?<C>\b\p{L}+) [-] \s* 
</p> \s*   (<(?<XX>div|p)[^<>]*>\s* </\g<XX>>\s* )* <p[^<>]*>
(?<D>[\p{L}]+\b )
|
(?x) (?<! \. (co|d ) )
(?<A>[\p{N}\p{L}–,—] )\s* (?<B>(</(\w+)>)*)?
</p> \s*   (<(?<XX>div|p)[^<>]*>\s* </\g<XX>>\s* )* <p[^<>]*>
(?<C>(<(\w+)\b[^<>]*>)*)?
 \s*(?<D>[\p{L}] )
|
(?x)(?-i)  (?<! \. (co|d ) )
(?<A>[\d\p{Ll}\p{N}] | \p{Ll}-)\s* (?<B>(</(\w+)>)*)?
</p> \s* (<(?<XX>div|p)[^<>]*>\s* </\g<XX>>\s* )*<p[^<>]*>
(?<C>(<(\w+)\b[^<>]*>)*)?
 \s*(?<D>[\p{Ll}] )  (?i)
|
(?x)(?-i)  (?<! \. (co|d ) )
(?<A>[’] | \p{L}-)\s* (?<B>(</(\w+)>)*)?
</p> \s*  (<(?<XX>div|p)[^<>]*>\s* </\g<XX>>\s* )*<p[^<>]*>
(?<C>(<(\w+)\b[^<>]*>)*)?
 \s*(?<D>[\p{L}] )  (?i)

|
(?x)(?i)  (?<! \. (co|d ) )
(?<A>\b (ca|Dr|Mr|Ms|Mrs|St) [.․] )\s* (?<B>(</(\w+)>)*)?
</p> \s*  (<(?<XX>div|p)[^<>]*>\s* </\g<XX>>\s* )*<p[^<>]*>
(?<C>(<(\w+)\b[^<>]*>)*)?
 \s*(?<D>[\p{L}] )  (?i)
```

Replace:

```
\g<A>\g<B> \g<C>\g<D>
```

Comment: FYI: Since this is the English language version of Stack Overflow, I translated your opening line into English. Be aware in the future that answers in anything other than English may get deleted. (I think that's unnecessary in this case, since the introduction wasn't especially relevant to the overall answer, but it's definitely something worth being aware of.)